# Trouble installing BH on R

Tags: r, package

I have Windows 10, R version 3.5.1. RStudio 1.1.456 and trying to install "BH". It doesn't work whether in R or in RStudio. It gives me the followint output and then freezes:

```
> install.packages("BH")
Installiere Paket nach ‘\\filer300/..../Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(da ‘lib’ nicht spezifiziert)
--- Bitte einen CRAN Spiegel für diese Sitzung auswählen ---
versuche URL 'https://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/BH_1.66.0-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 17880019 bytes (17.1 MB)
downloaded 17.1 MB
```

R stays frozen like this and you have to have to restart it. I tried to install other packages wich work

Comment: i dont see any error. what is the problem?

Comment: It's a big file.   Try downloading it manually via your brower or other means and point `install.packages()` to the zip file.

Comment: And as @Salman says, _there is no error_.  It takes a while to unpack it on Windows. Be patient.  Or use binary packages.